# How to embed a webpage inside a webpage for maximum support

Tags: html

What is the best way to embed a webpage inside a webpage for maximum support and according to standards?

I've heard an `<object>` with an `<embed />` inside and `<iframe />` alone.

Which is better and more proper to use; and more importantly, work more of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<iframe>` is fine, it was actually updated with the HTML 5 spec.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe for attribute status (deprecated, non-standard, new) and browser support.

Comment: oh, it was. Okay. I thought it was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `<iframe>` is the correct way to do it. Tutorial on IFRAME: http://manda.com/iframe/

Answer (score 0):

`<object>` and `<embed>` are often plugin related. If you want to show another page of your site, e.g., `http://www.example.com/page2.html`, on `http://www.example.com/page1.html`, use this on `page1.html`:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.example.com/page2.html"></iframe>
```

Height, width, borders, etc. can be defined in CSS.